# jest toEqual not working with exception matching

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm new to `jest` so I'm not sure if its my fault. So here is my test case

```
    it('should throw error if wrong email or phone number is provided', async () => {
      await expect(userService.verifyCredentials('invalidemail@invaliddomain.com', 'sayantan94'))
        .rejects
        .toEqual(new UnauthorizedException('Invalid email or phone number'));
    })
```

But this fails even though the same exception is thrown. Here is the output

```
FAIL  src/modules/user/user.service.spec.ts (5.156s)
● UserService › verifyCredentials › should throw error if wrong email or phone number is provided

expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  [Error: [object Object]]
Received:
  [Error: [object Object]]

Difference:

Compared values have no visual difference.

  88 |       await expect(userService.verifyCredentials('invalidemail@invaliddomain.com', 'sayantan94'))
  89 |         .rejects
> 90 |         .toEqual(new UnauthorizedException('Invalid email or phone number'));
     |          ^
  91 |     })
  92 |   })
  93 |
```

How do I check this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `toEqual` try `toThrow`

```
it('should throw error if wrong email or phone number is provided', async () =>  {        
    await expect(userService.verifyCredentials('invalidemail@invaliddomain.com', 'sayantan94'))
    .rejects
    .toThrow('Invalid email or phone number');
});
```

Ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#rejects